# R - substituting loop for row wise manipulation, may require taking lag of column being generated

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, rolling-computation

I have two tables

```
C_ID Loan_ID Loan
    A   L1      341
    A   L2      689
    A   L3      720
    A   L4      334
    B   L5      193
    B   L6      494
    B   L7      227


C_ID Prot_id Prot_value
    A   p1  506
    A   p2  366
    A   p3  263
    B   p4  529
    B   p5  414
```

Table 1 has loan details and table 2 has collateral details, both loans and collateral are at contract (C_ID) level; Collateral has be allocated to the loan with rule that highest collateral gets assigned first and first (L1 before L2 in same contract) loan gets the allocation first.

So finally, i should get

```
C_ID Loan_ID Loan Coll_ID Collateral Allocation
    A   L1    341        p1  506          341
    A   L1    341        p2  366          0
    A   L1    341        p3  263          0
    A   L2    689        p1  506          165
    A   L2    689        p2  366          366
    A   L2    689        p3  263          158
    A   L3    720        p1  506          0
    A   L3    720        p2  366          0
    A   L3    720        p3  263          105
    A   L4    334        p1  506          0
    A   L4    334        p2  366          0
    A   L4    334        p3  263          0
    B   L5    193        p4  529          193
    B   L5    193        p5  414          0
    B   L6    494        p4  529          336
    B   L6    494        p5  414          158
    B   L7    227        p4  529          0
    B   L7    227        p5  414          227
```

I was able to arrive at these using merge and loop; but loop (with supporting columns) takes lots of time big dataset.

```
  df3<-merge(x=df1,y=df2,by="C_ID")
  df3 <- mutate(df3,PreAllocation = 0,Allocation = 0, PostAllocation = 0,Residual = 0)
  for (i in 1:nrow(df3)){
          df3$PreAllocation[i] <- ifelse(df3$R2[i]==1,df3$Loan[i],df3$PostAllocation[i-1])
          df3$Allocation[i]<- ifelse(df3$R1[i] >1, min(df3$Residual[i - 
          df3$maxRank[i]],df3$PreAllocation[i]),min(df3$PreAllocation[i],df3$Prot_value[i]))
          df3$PostAllocation[i]<- df3$PreAllocation[i] - df3$Allocation[i]
          df3$Residual[i] <- ifelse(df3$R1[i]==1, (df3$Prot_value[i] - df3$Allocation[i]), 
              (df3$Residual[i-df3$maxRank[i]] - df3$Allocation[i]))    
 }
```

Anyone please help me with the alternate way to arrive at the Allocation column which can save time.

Thanks.

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized, so you don't need to loop on each row.  also, in your code, what is 'R1', 'R2' etc (not showed in the data)

Comment: Hi @akrun, if you are suggesting below code as the solution, it doesnt seem to work                                                                                                                  df3 <- mutate(df3,    PreAllocation = if_else(R2 == 1, Loan, lag(PostAllocation, n = 1)),
              Allocation = if_else(R3 > 1, pmin(lag(Residual, n = maxRank), PreAllocation),
              pmin(PreAllocation, Prot_value)),
              PostAllocation = PreAllocation - Allocation,
              Residual = if_else(R1 == 1, Prot_value - Allocation, lag(Residual, n = maxRank - Allocation)) )

Comment: As `R1` or `R2` is not showed in the data, it is not clear

Comment: @akrun, R1 is ranking of loan, R2 is ranking of collateral and maxR is maximum R2 under each contract.

Answer (score 0):

@akrun after merge and ranking, it may look like

```
C_ID    Loan_ID Loan    R1  Coll_ID Collateral  R2  maxRank
A       c       341     1       p1  506         1   3
A       c       341     1       p2  366         2   3
A       c       341     1       p3  263         3   3
A       a       689     2       p1  506         1   3
A       a       689     2       p2  366         2   3
A       a       689     2       p3  263         3   3
A       d       720     3       p1  506         1   3
A       d       720     3       p2  366         2   3
A       d       720     3       p3  263         3   3
A       b       334     4       p1  506         1   3
A       b       334     4       p2  366         2   3
A       b       334     4       p3  263         3   3
A       e       752     5       p1  506         1   3
A       e       752     5       p2  366         2   3
A       e       752     5       p3  263         3   3
B       h       193     1       p5  529         1   2
B       h       193     1       p4  414         2   2
B       g       494     2       p5  529         1   2
B       g       494     2       p4  414         2   2
B       f       227     3       p5  529         1   2
B       f       227     3       p4  414         2   2
B       j       785     4       p5  529         1   2
B       j       785     4       p4  414         2   2
B       i       371     5       p5  529         1   2
B       i       371     5       p4  414         2   2
B       k       395     6       p5  529         1   2
B       k       395     6       p4  414         2   2
```